# Extract data from a web page

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

I have a link to an app on Apple App Store. I need to use its data on my own webpage. To be more precise, I want to extract the app icon, its category and whether or not it is free and to add this data to my webpage. How can I do this using JavaScript?

Comment: You can't, you should use a serverside language for scraping like this.

Comment: And how would I do this using PHP?

Comment: Are you talking about client-side or server-side JavaScript? If client-side: that probably won't work.

Comment: @AnđelijaAnđelić Surely you can search for "PHP scraping" now.  (Something like [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) should do the job.)

Comment: @AnđelijaAnđelić check out http://bit.ly/YUo8RC

Comment: @MichaelW LMGTFY is blocked for a reason. Just say the idea in actual words or vote and/or move on.

Comment: Anything is possible! Using ajax with a Yahoo Pipe or YQL, or using node.js on the serverside would make this possible with javascript, it just does'nt makes sense when it's so easy to do on the serverside. I'd use cURL, but all you really have to do in PHP to get an external page is `file_get_content('http://mysite.com/page.php')`, and then you'll have to parse that to get what you want.

Comment: @adeneo It makes perfect sense to do server-side parsing in Javascript. See: [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/). The one major advantage is that for some webapps, you simply must use a real (ish) web browser to interact with them because of AJAX. Arguably this can (and was) done in other languages (e.g.: WATIR and Selenium), but if you're running a JS interpreter in the scraper one way or the other you're just making your life more complicated wrapping around it in another language. (I also can't recall a "real browser" scraper that's *headless* besides PhantomJS.)

Comment: @millimoose - Yeah, I've tried Phantom, written scrapers in node with express etc. but at the end of the day when doing something simple where speed is'nt essential, or if you're simply a newbie, using PHP where one line gets you the source of an external page, and an easy to use DomDocument class lets you find the elements you are looking for, makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, you can't do this using Javascript due to Cross Platform security issues.
You would nee a Web Server and possibly write a scraper in PHP to read that page. then call your PHP script from your JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the PHP Script:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/google+/id447119634?mt=8");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozzila/1.0");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);


$logo = explode('<div class="artwork">', $output);
$logo = explode('src="', $logo[1]);
$logo = explode('"', $logo[1]);
$logo = $logo[0];

$category = explode('<span class="label">Category:', $output);
$category = explode('">', $category[1]);
$category = explode('<', $category[1]);
$category = $category[0];

echo $logo;
echo $category;
?>
```